# Who has the winning hand in this Texas-holdem scenario?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

- The table cards were A,K,K,8,3.
- All four suits were on the board.
- Player one had A,8.
- Player two had A,3.

Is this a split pot?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, it is a split pot. Both players have AAKK8. You always make your best 5 card hand from the cards available. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands):

> A hand always consists of five cards. **In games where more than five cards are available to each player, the best five-card combination of those cards must be played.** Any cards not included in the hand do not affect its ranking. For example, if player A holds 3♠ Q♦ and player B holds 3♣ A♣, and five cards 4♣ 5♦ 6♦ 7♠ 10♥ are available to both players, the players hold equally ranking 3-4-5-6-7 straights despite the fact that the player B's ace ranks higher than the player A's queen.

Comment: Wow 20 upvotes. I guess i should start asking and answering poker questions.

Answer (score 5):

The best hand in either case would be two-pair with 8 as a kicker (A-A-K-K-8); it makes no difference if the 8 came from the table or from the hole cards.  Since suit also doesn't matter, the hands would tie.

So yes, it would be a split pot.

Answer (score 0):

If the table were A, K, K, 7, 3, the A-8 hand would win. The same would be true if the table were say, A, K, 8, 7, 3. Then the A-8 holder would have Aces and eights with a K kicker, while the A-3 holder would have A, A, 3,3, K, a weaker second pair.

But the actual table gives the A-3 holder A, A, K,K, 8, same as the A-8 holder.
That leads to a split pot.

The 8 on the table "counterfets" (nullifies) the effect of the superior 8 kicker held by the fist hand. At the same time, the second pair of kings means that the A-8 does NOT beat A-3 with the better second pair.