# flush on the board in texas hold'em poker

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Sherry:Q◇Q♧

Loren:7♡8◇

Board:10♤9♤2♤A♤3♤

Is this a split or does Sherry win and why?

Thanks Tammy

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12240/who-has-the-winning-hand-in-this-texas-holdem-scenario?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The pot is split.

In hold-em, each player is judged by the best 5 cards that they can put together between the board and their hand. In this case, for both players, that is just the five cards on the board. Sherry's queens cannot be used as kickers because they do not appear in the best five card hand.

Comment: You noticed this was a duplicate question but still provided an answer?

Comment: I have to admit, I wrote the answer and only then thought to check for similar questions.